# Graphing with Ipe

Tags: ipe

I am new to the TeX Stackexchange, so I want to apologize beforehand if I do not comply with the question-writing customs/rules.

My question is about the graphing program for LaTeX Ipe. I have downloaded it from the webpage, and when using it I am having trouble to insert math-mode text. For example, I click the "insert math" option, and write `\mathbb{R}` and it does not print out. Instead an error pops out saying:

```
***! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mathbb 

l.57 $\mathbb
             {R}$%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
Overfull \hbox (170.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 61--62
[][] 
 []
[1
{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (ipetemp.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1410 strings out of 493673
 17230 string characters out of 3143954
 75428 words of memory out of 3000000
 4817 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 5467 words of font info for 20 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,5n,35p,213b,119s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Progra
m Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Program Files/
MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on ipetemp.pdf (1 page, 17215 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)***
```

I am also having trouble to print `\mathscr{R}` and other symbols.

Furthermore, the math appears to being printed in "inline" mode, instead of in "display mode". Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you very much, and again, I apologize if the format of my question is not in line with the norms of the site.

Comment: `\mathbb` is from the `amssymb` package, so adding `\usepackage{amssymb} ` to the preamble of your document should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer and the edit! I am also new to Ipe, so could you clarify this for me? I downloaded it and I use "as if" it was Microsoft Paint (for example): I open it, draw, save, and export as .eps. I never write a preamble as in a latex document. How can I access such preamble? Is there a better way to use Ipe rather than the one i just described?

Comment: Done! I found it! Thank you very much! Do you have any idea of how to fix the second inquiry? The one about the "display math" mode

Comment: The `\mathscr` error will go away once you include `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` in your preamble. In general, whenever you get an "Undefined control symbol" error for a command `\blablabla`, just search for `blablabla` on this site, and almost certainly you'll infer the required packages the MWE are using `\blablabla`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Once I discovered where the preamble was (in the edit button) I can now use my LaTeX knowledge to solve for errors. By the way I could also solve the display math problem using the usual “\displaystyle” as in normal tex documents.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: It might still be helpful for someone who starts using Ipe. But im Ok if you fee it must be closed.

Comment: @agustromo I think it would be best if you wrote an answer summarising the comments that helped.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the question was answered in the comments, I will summarize the solution here so that it remains useful to other people. I thank Phelype Oleinik and  marmot for the help.

So basically, to get the `\mathbb{R}` and `\mathscr{R}` printed out in Ipe, you have to include the `\usepackage{amssymb, mathrsfs}` in the preamble of the document. To such preamble, you access by clicking on the *Edit* button and going to *Document properties*. You can also access with Ctrl+Shift+P.

In regard to the second inquiry, when you insert math mode text in Ipe, the text will automatically print out in "inline" math mode. To get the display math mode, before entering the desired math text, you have to include `\displaystyle` as in regular Latex documents.

Hope that this is also useful to other people!

Comment: Thanks for the nice post. I also had another issue. I cannot use `\text` inside ipe. Do you know how to handle this?